# Scala IDE (sbt project): Error instead of info

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using Scala IDE for working with a sbt project. I use it to work with Spark and MLlib.

I just run a simple example from the documentation. Everything seems right but the sbt output instead of reporting the log file with "debug" or "info" word in the start of each line, it uses "error" word in the start of each line:

this:

```
backgroung log: error: 15/04/2013 11:44:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 114.0 <TID 219> in 8 ms on localhost <1/4>
```

instead of this:

```
backgroung log: info: 15/04/2013 11:44:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 114.0 <TID 219> in 8 ms on localhost <1/4>
```

It's weird! I think it shouldn't use "error" because there is no error and it's just an information. What is your opinion?

Comment: I guess you should raise an issue here - https://github.com/sbt

Comment: It doesn't cause any problem in my codes but it's weird. I don't know how to open an issue in github. I should look for it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It looks like more the problem witg logger `backgroung log: error`. Can you provide your logger class as well?`